# Page blinking with default language and selected language when applied google translator

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to language google translation without page blinking . i am almost done with google translator working fine but when i select default language to another language the language translate successfully but the issue is after selection its blinking with default language and selected language how to resolve this .please share your knowledge about this.

below my code

```
  <script>
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({
            layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL
        }, 'google_translate_element');
    }

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>

 <div id="google_translate_element" class="googletranslatesec"></div>
```